# Postgres analogue to CROSS APPLY in SQL Server

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, cross-apply, lateral

I need to migrate SQL queries written for MS SQL Server 2005 to Postgres 9.1.
What is the best way to substitute for `CROSS APPLY` in this query?

```
SELECT *
FROM V_CitizenVersions         
CROSS APPLY     
       dbo.GetCitizenRecModified(Citizen, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName,
BirthYear, BirthMonth, BirthDay, ..... ) -- lots of params
```

`GetCitizenRecModified()` function is a table valued function. I can't place code of this function because it's really enormous, it makes some difficult computations and I can't abandon it.

Comment: You don't need cross apply in Postgres. You can use a table function just like a function. Simply join them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - `CROSS APPLY` re-executes the TVF with correlated parameters rather than executing once and then joining the result.

Comment: I realise this is ancient...
@MartinSmith that is not necessarily the case on MSSQL if that function is of the inline-table-valued variety, see Paul White's write up on how the MSSQL query planner can sometimes optimize `apply` into a `join` : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/ 
Since we don't see the original code here I am speculating that's what happened based on the comment re performance on Erwin's answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Postgres **9.3** or later use a **`LATERAL`** join:

```sql
SELECT v.col_a, v.col_b, f.*  -- no parentheses, f is a table alias
FROM   v_citizenversions v
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL f_citizen_rec_modified(v.col1, v.col2) f ON true
WHERE  f.col_c = _col_c;
```

Why `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON true`?

- [Record returned from function has columns concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392371/record-returned-from-function-has-columns-concatenated/25392910#25392910)

---

For **older versions**, there is a very simple way to accomplish what *I think* you are trying to with a set-returning function ([`RETURNS TABLE` or `RETURNS SETOF record` OR `RETURNS record`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)):

```
SELECT *, (f_citizen_rec_modified(col1, col2)).*
FROM   v_citizenversions v
```

The function computes values once for every row of the outer query. If the function returns multiple rows, resulting rows are multiplied accordingly. All **parentheses are syntactically required** to decompose a row type. The table function could look something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_citizen_rec_modified(_col1 int, _col2 text)
  RETURNS TABLE(col_c integer, col_d text)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT s.col_c, s.col_d
FROM   some_tbl s
WHERE  s.col_a = $1
AND    s.col_b = $2
$func$;
```

You need to wrap this in a subquery or CTE if you want to apply a `WHERE` clause because the columns are not visible on the same level. (And it's better for performance anyway, because you **prevent repeated evaluation** for every output column of the function):

```sql
SELECT col_a, col_b, (f_row).*
FROM  (
   SELECT col_a, col_b, f_citizen_rec_modified(col1, col2) AS f_row
   FROM   v_citizenversions v
   ) x
WHERE (f_row).col_c = _col_c;
```

There are several other ways to do this or something similar. It all depends on what you want exactly.

Comment: i used the query you proposed. now i'm shocked: the query executes more than a minute. in ms sql it takes less than a second O_O.

Comment: @user1178399: It's practically impossible to comment on that without knowing the many factors in play. I would speculate that the performance can be improved.

Comment: I would suggest that the reason for the performance difference is that the original MSSQL query is probably _not_ executing the function for every row. The function is likely an inline-table-valued-function (ITVF) and the query optimizer has executed is as a `join` rather than a correlated query for every row. In that case using `lateral` is an unfair comparison. In any rdbms, executing a user-defined (in sql) function for every row is a terrible idea. There's a good example of how MSSQL query planner can optimize ITVF here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/

Comment: We can use CROSS JOIN with returning table function, it avoid "ON TRUE" 

SELECT v.col_a, v.col_b, f.*  
FROM   v_citizenversions v
CROSS JOIN f_citizen_rec_modified(v.col1, v.col2) f

Answer (score 32):

Necromancing:
New in PostgreSQL 9.3:

The LATERAL keyword

left | right | inner JOIN **LATERAL**

`INNER JOIN LATERAL` is the same as `CROSS APPLY` 
and `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` is the same as `OUTER APPLY`

Example usage:

```
SELECT * FROM T_Contacts 

--LEFT JOIN T_MAP_Contacts_Ref_OrganisationalUnit ON MAP_CTCOU_CT_UID = T_Contacts.CT_UID AND MAP_CTCOU_SoftDeleteStatus = 1 
--WHERE T_MAP_Contacts_Ref_OrganisationalUnit.MAP_CTCOU_UID IS NULL -- 989


LEFT JOIN LATERAL 
(
    SELECT 
         --MAP_CTCOU_UID    
         MAP_CTCOU_CT_UID   
        ,MAP_CTCOU_COU_UID  
        ,MAP_CTCOU_DateFrom 
        ,MAP_CTCOU_DateTo   
   FROM T_MAP_Contacts_Ref_OrganisationalUnit 
   WHERE MAP_CTCOU_SoftDeleteStatus = 1 
   AND MAP_CTCOU_CT_UID = T_Contacts.CT_UID 

    /*  
    AND 
    ( 
        (__in_DateFrom <= T_MAP_Contacts_Ref_OrganisationalUnit.MAP_KTKOE_DateTo) 
        AND 
        (__in_DateTo >= T_MAP_Contacts_Ref_OrganisationalUnit.MAP_KTKOE_DateFrom) 
    ) 
    */
   ORDER BY MAP_CTCOU_DateFrom 
   LIMIT 1 
) AS FirstOE ON true
```

Answer (score 2):

I like Erwin Brandstetter's answer however, I've discovered a performance problem:
when running

```
SELECT *, (f_citizen_rec_modified(col1, col2)).*
FROM   v_citizenversions v
```

The f_citizen_rec_modified function will be ran 1 time for every column it returns (multiplied by every row in v_citizenversions).  I did not find documentation for this effect, but was able to deduce it by debugging. Now the question becomes, how can we get this effect (prior to 9.3 where lateral joins are available) without this performance robbing side effect?

Update: I seem to have found an answer. Rewrite the query as follows:

```
select x.col1, x.col2, x.col3, (x.func).* 
FROM (select SELECT v.col1, v.col2, v.col3, f_citizen_rec_modified(col1, col2) func
FROM   v_citizenversions v) x
```

The key difference being getting the raw function results first (inner subquery) then wrapping that in another select that busts those results out into the columns. This was tested on PG 9.2

Answer (score 1):

This link appears to show how to do it in Postgres 9.0+:

[PostgreSQL: parameterizing a recursive CTE](http://explainextended.com/2010/12/24/postgresql-parametrizing-a-recursive-cte/)

It's further down the page in the section titled "Emulating CROSS APPLY with set-returning functions".  Please be sure to note the list of limitations after the example.

Comment: I'm surprised the link only police haven't jumped on this.