# Combine postgres function with query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I currently struggle with the output of a sql-function which I require in my result-set:

```
SELECT getAdditionalInfoAboutDate(date) from sampleCalendar
```

The problem is, that I get the result in the following way:

1. "Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3"
2. "Attribute2, Attribute3, Attribute4"
3. ...

As you can see I get my desired result but it only has one column even though my function returns 3 columns.

When I try to create a statement like:

```
SELECT (Select * from getAdditionalInfoAboutDate(date)) from sampleCalendar
```

I get the exception "subquery must return only one column".

Do I have the chance to solve this somehow?

Edit: Found the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472790/analogue-to-cross-apply) which is:

```
SELECT getAdditionalInfoAboutDate(date).* from sampleCalendar
```

Comment: How about having the function return the date too and then do `select * from getAdditionalInfoAboutDate(date)`?

Comment: This also results in "subquery must return only one column"

Comment: What is the type or the returned value? `record` ? Could you please give more code about your function ?

Comment: nevermind, see my edited question - found the answer in a different thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [the answer you found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472790/analogue-to-cross-apply), but there may be a better answer depending on what your function actually returns: one or multiple rows? Assuming ***one*** row.

What you have in the question is *incorrect* either way. **The row expression must be enclosed in parentheses to decompose it**, else the syntax is ambiguous. It must be:

```
SELECT (getAdditionalInfoAboutDate(date)).* FROM sampleCalendar;
```

However, Postgres has a weak spot here. It would evaluate the function multiple times - once for every column in the result. To **optimize performance** put the function call in a subquery:

```sql
SELECT (f_row).*
FROM  (
   SELECT getAdditionalInfoAboutDate(date) AS f_row
   FROM   sampleCalendar
   ) sub;
```

Or use a **`LEFT JOIN LATERAL`** in pg 9.3+

```sql
SELECT f_row.*  -- no parentheses here, it's a table alias
FROM   sampleCalendar s
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL getAdditionalInfoAboutDate(s.date) f_row ON true
```

More details:

- [Record returned from function has columns concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392371/record-returned-from-function-in-query-has-columns-concatenated-in-postgresql/25392910#25392910)