# SQL INNER JOIN: ORDER BY LIMIT duplicates from one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, limit

I have 2 tables without identical primary key between them (`id` exist in both, primary only for table `A`). I want to use the primary key of the first table `A` for the `ON` clause. Therefore I'll have duplicates from the second table `B`. I want to `GROUP BY` the duplicates based on some field `B.cnt` and always take the first one - `DESC LIMIT 1`.

This is what I tried (DBMS is PostgreSQL):

```
SELECT 
    scheme1.A.some_attr, 
    B.some_attr
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM scheme2.B ORDER BY scheme2.B.cnt DESC LIMIT 1) AS B
INNER JOIN
    scheme1.A
ON
    scheme1.A.id = B.id
;
```

The query returns single record. While the desired behavior is to return single record just for each set of records from `B` having same `id` (based on the criteria mentioned). So in total the query of course will return multiple records...

How can I achieve the desired result?

Thanks,

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rank() window analytical function, see [Postgres Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT          
                scheme1.A.some_attr, 
                scheme2.B.some_attr,                     
                rank() OVER (PARTITION BY B.ID ORDER BY scheme2.B.cnt, scheme2.B.another_attr DESC) as rnk
                FROM 
                                scheme1.A
                INNER JOIN
                                scheme2.B
                ON
                                scheme2.B.id = scheme2.A.id
) A WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue should be this line:

```
(SELECT * FROM scheme2.B ORDER BY scheme2.B.cnt DESC LIMIT 1) scheme2.B
```

It's being treated as following:

```
(SELECT * FROM scheme2.B ORDER BY scheme2.B.cnt DESC LIMIT 1) AS scheme2.B
```

Where `scheme.B` alias is obviously incorrect, change it following and it should work

```
SELECT 
    scheme1.A.some_attr, 
    scheme2.B.some_attr
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM scheme2.B ORDER BY scheme2.B.cnt DESC LIMIT 1) AS B
INNER JOIN
    scheme1.A
ON
    scheme1.A.id = B.id
;
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT 
    scheme1.A.some_attr, 
    scheme2.B.some_attr
FROM 
    scheme1.A
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (SELECT * FROM scheme2.B WHERE scheme2.B.id = scheme2.A.id ORDER BY scheme2.B.cnt DESC LIMIT 1) AS B ON TRUE
;
```

If it's a single attribute, you could do the following:

```
SELECT 
    scheme1.A.some_attr, 
    (
        SELECT 
            scheme2.B.some_attr
        FROM
            scheme2.B
        WHERE
            scheme2.B.id = scheme2.A.id
        ORDER BY scheme2.B.cnt DESC LIMIT 1
    )
FROM 
    scheme1.A
;
```

Comment: It's solved the syntax error, but the query returns in total single record, which is not what I expected. I do want just single record out of each set of duplicate records from B having same id. I'l edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I think you're looking for Lateral Join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472790/postgres-analogue-to-cross-apply-in-sql-server. I'll my answer accordingly. I'm not a PostgreSQL expert, but this seems like what you're looking for.

Comment: It worked and returned what seems to be correct number of records, however the attributes from the table B: scheme2.B.some_attr returned all NULLS.

Comment: data is correct yes, the second option (inner select) works fine

Comment: @michael seems that ` ON TRUE` statement has to be added, let me update, and check then :)